# Round border appear after click button

Tags: html, css

I trying to make a border appear around the circle button after clicking but the border is a rounded square instead of a circle.

```css
.dot {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
}

.dot:after {
  border: solid 1px #232323;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button class="dot" style="background-color: #cc6c6c;"></button>
```

Comment: `:after` doesn't do what you think it does (It affects a pseudo-element) The black outline you are seeing is an outline that is applied as part of the focus style in Chrome, not a border.

Comment: `:after` is CSS2, you actually need to use `::after` which is sued as pesudoelement for CSS3. However that does not change anything afetr a button click. Its used for adding somethign after that element. If you have the button as a link, you can use `:visited` you can use `:focus` or need JS with an onclick event to change style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the `:focus` selector instead of `:after`, and need to hide the default `outline` property to make your alternative focus style (using a border) visible.

(You also don't need to re-set the `border-radius` property, since it hasn't changed)

To avoid the button jumping when focused, you can use a transparent border on your initial button style, see the CSS comment in the example.

```css
.dot {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  /* 
    Using an transparent border, rather than no border,
    will prevent the focus style from causing the button to 
    jump down by the border thickness (1px in this case) 
  */
  border: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.dot:focus {
  border-color: #232323;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="dot" style="background-color: #cc6c6c;"></button>
```

Comment: This is preferable to other approaches in that it replaces `outline` with a different `focus` behavior that is more likely to be [WCAG compliant](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/focus-visible.html).  However, make sure that the `focus`-state is sufficiently visible/obvious.

Comment: Thank you, but I notice when the button is clicked, the position will move down a bit, how do I avoid this?

Comment: The simplest way, would be to give the button an invisible border when not focused, so when you add a new border the height doesn't change. I will expand my answer.